# Like best/the best like most/the most

Tags: grammar

I like pet animals better than cattle = 'Correct'may be a little informal to some or even "colloquial" if you like, but  completely understandable,  and widely used by English speakers.?

I like pet animals more than cattle= 'correct'and more formal.in other words, it's the way you would like to speak or write in a more formal context and it  would be very clear in almost any context.

I like chocolate and sweets but  i like peanut  best.= 'correct' and widely used by English speakers even though may be considered as a little informal.

I like chocolate and sweets  but i like peanut the most= 'correct' and more formal.

I like chocolate and sweets but i like peanut The best. " not sure if it is grammatically correct or constantly used by English speakers.

I like chocolate and sweets but i like peanut most. "Sounds good to me, but not sure if it is correct usage or grammar.

Based on the above ASSUMPTIONS  , are the following  sentences correct?

Everybody in that house knows how to fix cars, but the oldest brother knows best .

Everybody in that house knows how to fix cars ,but the oldest brother knows the best.

Everybody in that house knows how to fix cars, but the oldest brother knows the most.

All my sisters play volleyball, but María,the youngest, plays best.

All my sisters play volleyball, but María,the youngest, plays the best.="she does it better than the rest"

All my sisters play volleyball,but María, the youngest, plays the most.= "she does it more often"

So,according to my understanding, depending on the Verb in the sentence, i should use best/the best/ most/the most Not interchangibly.otherwise, the meaning of the sentence would be very different:

" we all tell jokes in this office,but John actually tells The best"= his jokes are the funniest.  Vs    "we all tell jokes in this office,but John actually tells the most"= John tells jokes more Often than the rest.

Please NOTE  these are only ASSUMPTIONS .

I'm looking for correctness.

Comment: Your assumptions are mostly about *context / semantics*, not the precise phrasing. Assumption #1: *I love you more than **your husband*** (more than *he loves you*); Assumption #2: *I love you more than **life itself*** (more than *I love [my] life itself*).

Comment: Yeah Fumble. Context is what i was looking for. But i sometimes have trouble finding the way to arrange or conveying my ideas because i don't have a good grasp of English. That's why sometimes my questions seem to be a Statement  and my statements are fairly incorrect most of the time. Knowing how to use these phrases in context,  is what i'm aiming for. Are the "context" aspect of my sentences correct? Please help me !✌

Answer (score 1):

You are asking too many questions.

Skipping the first, because comparing pets with cattle is pretty weird.

None of your three sentences about snack preference reads well

> I like chocolate and sweets but i like peanut best.
>
> I like chocolate and sweets but i like peanut the most.
>
> I like chocolate and sweets but i like peanut The best.

because they mention two snacks but imply there are others. For example if you prefer caviar to peanut, then you do not like peanut most. So I suggest

> I like chocolate and sweets but I like peanuts better.

because it restricts the ideas to what is written in the sentence. Note the plural *peanuts*.

Comment: Yes.i got your point. Now i see the mistake.